# Transform an external RSS feed with XSLT

Tags: xslt, rss, xml-parsing

I have a blog hosted on wordpress and I want to be able to grab the RSS feed and parse it into another website using XSLT. I'm trying to parse it on the client side so I can just plug in the link to the feed and utilize it for real-time updates.

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
    function loadXMLDoc(dname){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
            xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else{
            xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
        xhttp.send("");
        return xhttp.responseXML;
    }

    function displayResult(){
        xml=loadXMLDoc("http://myBlog.wordpress.com/feed");
        xsl=loadXMLDoc("styles.xsl");
        // code for IE
        if (window.ActiveXObject){
          ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
          document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
        }
        // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument){
            xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
            xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
            resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
            document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
        }
    }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="displayResult()">
        <div id="example"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my xsl doc that I am using to format the feed I am getting from my blog. When I view the HTML file I am not getting any errors, but the page is simply blank with nothing on it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss"
xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <body>
<xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </p>
</xsl:for-each>
 </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The first thing I would check is if your RSS feed has a default namespace.

Comment: You are likely running into Same Origin Policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy restrictions that are preventing you from fetching the RSS XML

Comment: @DevNull No specific namespaces. I'm not sure if this is even possible, given the fact that I can't manipulate the feed to include a reference to my xsl style sheet. Please, if anyone has done this client-side, I would love to know how!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement xsl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902186/how-to-implement-xsl)