# How to implement xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, hyperlink

I'm new to all of this, and I've been searching like hell, and can't find any guide that assumes little prior knowledge. So if you could keep answers as simple as possible, that would be great for us newbies :)

I have a document, xml.xml, that I would like to transform using another file called xslt.xsl

I've used the [W3schools tryit editor](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog) to get the code for both files.

Now how do I get them to work together on my computer?

I've tried adding

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl" href="http://www.dansitrepairs.com/XSLT.xsl"?>
```

to the second line of my xml file, but it doesn't work.

I've tried linking it in Dreamweaver and msxsl too. Clearly I must have ignored something important, because it shouldn't be this hard (I don't think)

Thanks

**Added**

As outilined in the comments, it was partly due to a typo in the code I provided, namely type='text/xsl"  should be double quoted.

However, it only works when both files are local. When the xsl reference is on a server, I get this instead of what I want:
[image: What I get]

**Added #2**

> It probably is a cross-origin policy implemented on your browser. It
>   should work when both files are on a server on the same domain.

This was the other problem

Comment: Does it work if you don't involve a web server and just try it out locally on the filesystem? If xml.xml and XSLT.xsl are in the same directory, try using `<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl" href="XSLT.xsl"?>`.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at [Why isn't my stylesheet applied?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#Why_isn.27t_my_stylesheet_applied.3F) in XSL Transformations in Mozilla FAQ.

Comment: Perhaps this is a typo in your post only, but you use a single quote where it should be double here: `type='text/xsl"`.

Comment: @MathiasMüller This was a typo in the actual code, great spot! I got this from another stackoverflow post, but can't remember where (and by now it's sunk into the depths of my research history)

Comment: @mzjn That worked! But why does it not work when it involves a web server?

Comment: If this was a typo in the actual code, try again on the web server.

Comment: @MathiasMüller It doesn't work when going via the server with the corrected code, no idea why

Comment: What exactly do you mean by involving a web server? Do you open the XML file that references the stylesheet locally with a browser? Or are both files on the web server? Please answer by editing your post.

Comment: It probably is a cross-origin policy implemented on your browser. It should work when both files are on a server on the same domain.

Comment: @PollyShaw, please formulate this as answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: simple use xml-stylesheet tag in your xml

Comment: @KamranShahid: Please read the question first. This is not the problem the OP is facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably is a cross-origin policy implemented on your browser. It should work when both files are on a server on the same domain.